# Avoiding the `attr_accessible` setting and returning a boolean value from the updating action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to update an ActiveRecord avoiding the `attr_accessible` setting but returning a *boolean value* from the updating method. [I know](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D) that, in order to avoid the `attr_accessible` setting, I can use this

```
@user.send :attributes=, @attrib, false
```

but that doesn't return a *boolean value*.

---

I need that because I must handle updating success (when the update method returns `true`) or fault (when the update method returns `false`) behaviour in someway like this:

In the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #none
  # or
  # attr_protected :name, :surname
end
```

In the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # The following is the behaviour that I would like to handle (it is just an example: it is wrong and doesn't work)
  if @user.send(:attributes=, { :name => params[:name], :surname => params[:surname] }, false) 
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

---

**Is it possible? If so, how? If no, there is another way to do that?**

P.S.: In order to avoid AJAX injections, for me *it is important to update only a limited number of attributes and do not update the `@user` ActiveRecord* (see code in the example above) *at all* (maybe I don't must use some method like a "global" `save`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper method to bypass mass-assignment protected attributes is to use assign_attributes (only available in Rails 3.1+).

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes

Here's an example:

```
user.assign_attributes({ :name => 'Joe' }, :without_protection => true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `attributes=` with `false` doesn't update anything yet, it just sets the attribute values while ignoring any `attr_accessible` whitelist.

So you can just call `save` afterwards, which returns the boolean value you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure of that... Can you be more precise? Maybe, can you post some links where I can read about that to understand what are you saying?

Comment: Are you sure of what are you saing? Can someone confirm that?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Try it on the console and you will see that `attributes=` does not write to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my gem [sudo_attributes](https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes), it may provide the functionality you're looking for. I built it to make it easier to handle protected attributes by adding "sudo" methods such as `@model.sudo_update_attributes(params[:model])` when you know you can trust the input. The README has some examples.